# Timer keeps continuously loading a scene instead of just once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a simple timer script, after the timer reaches 0 it loads a new scene. But it keeps continuously loading the scene instead of once not allowing the scene it loads to be played. I just need it to load the scene once.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
 {
public float timelimit;
public Text text;

public void ChangeScene(int changeTheScene)

{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(changeTheScene);
}

void Update()
{
    timelimit -= Time.deltaTime;
    text.text = "TimerText:" + Mathf.Round(timelimit);
    if (timelimit < 0)
    {
        timelimit = 0;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*NOTE:* your code as described won't cause the issue you describe. I see two possibilities:

- your newly loaded scene has the same component in it, which repeatedly loads the scene
- you are actually loading the scene *additively* so this component continues to run after the load.

Assuming the latter, if you follow your code through, you'll see that your `if` statement has a condition that will *always* be true once the timelimit is reached:

Every frame you subtract a number from `timelimit`. Then, if `timelimit` is now less than zero, set `timelimit` to zero and load the scene.

If you've set timelimit to zero in the previous frame, and then subtract a number, it will *always* be less than zero: you'll always load the scene again on each subsequent frame.

Try instead using a boolean variable to track whether you've loaded the scene or not. Or alternatively, destroy the component as soon as you load the scene, so that your code stops running.

If the problem is actually that you have this component in your new scene, too... consider removing it! :-)

**EDIT:**

> Try instead using a boolean variable to track whether you've loaded
>   the scene or not.

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timelimit;
    public Text text;
    static bool loadedScene = false;

    public void ChangeScene(int changeTheScene)

    {
        //SceneManager.LoadScene(changeTheScene);
    }



    void Update()
    {
        //Exit if we have already loaded scene
        if (loadedScene)
        {
            //Destroy Timer Text
            Destroy(text.gameObject);
            //Destroy this Timer GameObject and Script
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        timelimit -= Time.deltaTime;
        text.text = "TimerText:" + Mathf.Round(timelimit);
        if (timelimit < 0)
        {
            timelimit = 0;
            loadedScene = true; //We have loaded Scene so mark it true
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, my new scene does not have the same component in the new scene. So what happens in you play in the "Game scene" once the timer reaches 0 i want to load the "End scene" but once i load the end scene i also keep components from the "Game scene" into the "End scene" all i need is the text from the timer to be visible in the End scene.

Comment: Hi again Dan, Im trying to destroy the timer and its text, if i destroy the timer everything works fine, if i destroy the text it pauses the game in Unity and you are unable to play. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jakethagun Modified Dan's answer with an example code. It uses static boolean variable to do that. You can also use PlayerPrefs to do this.

Comment: Thanks alot @programmer

Answer (score 0):

You're timelimit might not be initialized. Did you make sure it isn't set to 0 in the Unity Editor?

Comment: If it wasn't initialized wouldn't it be not loading the scene at all, it is loading the scene needed but it doesn't stop loading it once it has been loaded once.

Comment: I didn't knew that it worked once ;) - that changes the situation. - After calling `SceneManager.LoadScene` you might want to set the timelimit to 9999 for example. To check if the problem might be that the Update method of the Timer is called another time before loading the next Scene. Another thing you might want to change is that in the Update method the call is directly on the scene manager instead of the `ChangeScene` method of you wrote.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)